# how to add value to invisible date textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview, default

I'm triyng to do something for 3 days but I can't.

I have two calenders. one is always appears and the second calender2 I hide it from user when he select a specific value in a previous dropdown list.

now ,when the user doesn't insert a value in the calender2 textbox which is hided it's take an initial or defualt date (1900/01/01)

what I'm trying to do is set calender2 teaxtbox equals to the value of calender1 textbox if the user doesn't select a value to calender 2 that is hided (I prefer this) , or at least I want to set the textbox empty when there is no value selected

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime pastday = e.Day.Date;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int year = date.Year;
    int month = date.Month;
    int day = date.Day;
    DateTime today = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    if (pastday.CompareTo(today) < 0)
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}

protected void Calendar2_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime pastday = e.Day.Date;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int year = date.Year;
    int month = date.Month;
    int day = date.Day;
    DateTime today = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    if (pastday.CompareTo(today) < 0)
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Render` event? I think you should be using some `OnChange` one. Shouldn't you set calendar2 = calendar1 when that dropdown is changed and you hide calendar2? And by the way, you can use `DateTime.Today` instead of those four lines, and it's "hidden", not "_hided_".

Comment: Still there, amjad?